# Square integrable stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose that for a stochastic process we have

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T}X^{2}(t)dt \right]<\infty
\end{align}

where $T<\infty$. Does it  holds that $|X(t)|<M$, where $M$ constant? I am a little confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement $|X(t)|<M$ can be interpreted in two different ways: Either

$$\exists M: |X(t,\omega)| \leq M \, \quad \text{for all} \, \omega \in \Omega \tag{1}$$

(i.e. the bound is uniform for all $\omega \in \Omega$) or

$$\forall \omega \in \Omega \, \, \exists M=M(\omega): |X_t(\omega)| \leq M. \tag{2}$$

- $(1)$ is in general not correct. To see this, simply consider a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$: From $\mathbb{E}(B_t^2) = t$, we get that
  $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T X_t^2 \, dt \right) = \frac{T^2}{2}< \infty.$$
  On the other hand, there does not exist $M$ such that $(1)$ is satisfied since this would contradict $\mathbb{P}(|B_t|>M)>0$ (which follows from $B_t \sim N(0,t)$).
- $(2)$ usually holds, but it has little to do with condition $$\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^T X_t^2 \, dt \right)<\infty.$$ Rather it is a consequence of the fact that cádlág (or cáglád) processes are considered - and these are bounded (in the sense of $(2)$) on any finite time interval.

Comment: Will a.s continuity help us getting closer in some way? If not bound on the process what about the expectation?

Comment: @Icocrane Closer to $(1)$, you mean? As you can see from my counterexample, continuity doesn't help (... because Brownian motion has continuous sample paths). And no, I don't think that bounds on the expectation are helpful...

Comment: No, I am refering to obtaing bounds on the expectation of the process of type say $\mathbb{E}supX < \infty$ kinda uniformly as in 1. Having that in conclusion and not in hypoteses.

Comment: Actually I have this question pendning that I wrote before if you wanna take a look at it.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025159/bounded-moments-for-continuous-processes. It might be easier to understand what I am asking.

Comment: @Icocrane I will take a look at it later today.