# Bounded moments for continuous processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am trying to prove that an $a.s$ continuous  $\mathbb{R}$-valued process have bounded moments on a compact set.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: You have to make some assumptions on existence of moments of individual r.v.'s in the process. An obvious counterexample to your claim is the process $X_t=tX$ where $X$ has Cauchy distribution.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy what about square integrable? Or can one make it for weaker?

Comment: Do you have a specific application in mind? As was already pointed out, the assertion does in general fail to hold and I think that it is pretty difficult to give any reasonable condition without having further assumptions on the process. For instance it is well-known that martingales satisfy maximal inequalities of the form $$\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{s \leq t} |M_s|^p \right) \leq C(p) \mathbb{E}(|M_t|^p), \qquad p>1$$  but it is not reasonable to expect such kind of inequalities for general processes.

Comment: @saz Right, not really, Ive just seen it been used many times and it made we wanna obtain some good ways to handle it. It is also analogous to the contious on compact of basic analysis which makes it interesting